# Responding to a broken laser beam?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

Firstly, I must apologise as I'm a complete noob but the Arduino kits / lego pieces are fantastic and I can't stop tinkering.  Unfortunatley my knowledge does not match my passion.

I picked up a laser from [Amazon: FamilyMall(TM) KY-008 Laser Transmitter Module 650nm 5V Diode For Arduino AVR PIC](http://www.amazon.co.uk/FamilyMall-KY-008-Transmitter-Module-Arduino/dp/B00KYHL7HO).

I'm wondering what the middle pin is good for and if I can somehow manage to detect and respond to the beam being broken?

Thanks for looking. :)

Comment: http://www.linksprite.com/wiki/images/thumb/1/1a/KY008.png/300px-KY008.png . Middle pin should be 5v, so I think you miswired it. Signal I'd guess is kind of like an on/off switch.

Comment: @Gerben - I don't think it's of the highest quality, the '-' labelled pin is VCC and the 'S' pin is gnd.  Connected this way results in a functional beam.  I suspect the manufacturer is a troll :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a data sheet or the device on hand not sure what the middle pin is used for.  On the topic of detecting a broken beam the item you purchased is purely an emitter, in order to detect the beam being broken there are two main ways, using a photodetector on the "opposite end" of the beam but this means having wires trailing the same path as the laser beam, alternatively you could mount a mirror where the beam lands and reflect it back to a photodetector mounted close to the laser diode.  You would them use the arduino to detect the state of the photodetector.

Comment: thank you!  That's exactly what I wanted to know.  I'll look into picking up a photodetector, assuming they're not mega expensive and continue playing.  thanks again!

Comment: can I ask if you'd mind looking at this item: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Generic-TCRT5000L-TCRT5000-Reflective-Infrared/dp/B00C0P98C4/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1429054085&sr=1-2&keywords=photodetector and saying if you think that this would be more suitable instead of buying the separate photodetector you mention

Comment: @SteveGreen That item you linked is fine *if* you want to detect paper, card or some other reflective material at a maximum distance of 12mm. If that's *not* what you want to do, then it's not suitable.

Comment: thanks @RogerRowland.  I was mainly jsut trying to mess around with setting off a buzzer if a door was opened or something along those lines.  My 'plan' is to play with automation stuff but I'm waiting on a ton of stuff to be delivered and might have bought a lot of 'bit' that are not neccesary but still fun to play with and learn how the arduino etc works :)

Comment: Sorry took so long to see your follow up, I assume you have found it to be a fairly powerful laser so you could use the mirror trick over quite a distance.  I looked this up for you to give you some ideas to get it done on the cheap:  http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Laser-Tripwire/

Comment: oh and just in case it's still relevant no the items you linked to would not work.  They have a filter that selectively blocks "all" wavelengths of light apart from the one its interested in ie in this case 950nm .  Your laser on the other hand produces light in the 650nm wavelength and in theory would be blocked by the filter on the photodiode.  If you looked you may find one with a 650nm filter which would be perfect for your application.